# Visualizing gradient descent for linear regression - intercept parameter not learned well.

Tags: javascript, d3.js, statistics, data-visualization, gradient-descent

I'm writing a little d3.js visualization for univariate linear regression, where the two parameters are learned via gradient descent on the cost function (sum of squared error a.k. a. *SSE*)).

As of now, we get to see the line of best fit adjust as gradient descent iterates toward the cost-minimizing choice of parameters, 'alpha', and 'beta', where

```
 y_i = alpha + beta * x_i
```

In javascript, the data is represented as an array of objects with 'x' and 'y' attributes. The data are generated as follows:

1. First, *X* is sampled from a uniform distribution between 'lowBound' and 'upBound'
2. Next, *Y* is sampled according to the data-generating process: 
   y = 3x - 10 + error,

where error is sampled from a normal distribution with mean zero and variance **errorVariance**.

I've written some d3.js code to implement gradient descent, and when I watch the visualization, it seems that the intercept term is not being learned correctly. This is because the algorithm frequently adjusts the slope parameter, but only adjusts the intercept parameter very slightly from its initial value (chosen randomly). There are three possibilities:

1. I've made a mistake in my mathematics (or javascript represenation of the mathematics).
2. I've made a mistake in my visualization (e.g. d3 SVG stuff).
3. I've made no mistakes, and the partial derivative of the *SSE* with respect to the intercept parameter *alpha* is much smaller than with respect to the slope parameter, so it makes sense that gradient descent does not adjust *alpha* much.

I can't really figure out what the answer is. So I'll post a simplified setup of my code, and hopefully someone may be able to shed some light for me.  You can also see the visualization in its current form (and view the full source) [here](http://people.reed.edu/~jmenick/linregDynamic.html). Let's only worry about the math for now. If someone would like for me to post my code that joins the data to svg elements, I'd be happy to, but I think it's more likely that the problem lies here.

```
  // Section 1: GENERATE DATA                                                      


  var n = 60;                                                                      
  var upBound = 20;                                                                
  var lowBound = -20;                                                              
  var errorVariance = 6;                                                           
  var data = []                                                                    


  // grab a random x value.                                                        
  var randomX = function() {                                                       
      return Math.random() * (upBound - lowBound) + lowBound;                      
  }                                                                                

  // zero-mean normally distributed error.                                         
  var error = d3.random.normal(0, errorVariance);                                  

  // The following function defines the "data-generating-process":                 
  // y = 3x - 10 + error                                                           
  var dgp = function(x) {                                                          
      return 3*x - 10 + error();                                                   
  }                                                                                

  // Randomly generate data according to the dgp.                                  
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {                                                    
      var newX = randomX()                                                         
      var newY = dgp(newX);                                                        
      data.push({                                                                  
          "x": newX,                                                               
          "y": newY                                                                
      });                                                                          
  }
```

That's all fine and dandy.  Then in Section 2, I provide the utilities for doing gradient descnet.

```
  // define parameters for Gradient Descent                                                                                                       
  var learningRate = 0.00001;                                                                                                                     
  var convThreshold = 0.005;                                                                                                                      


  // Per Observation Cost Function                                                                                                                
  var obsCost = function(alpha, beta, data, i) {                                                                                                  
      return .5 * Math.pow(((alpha + beta * data[i]["x"]) - data[i]["y"]), 2);                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                                               

  // Sum of Squared Errors                                                                                                                        
  var costFuncLR = function(alpha, beta, data) {                                                                                                  
      var sse = 0;                                                                                                                                
      for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {                                                                                                               
          sse += obsCost(alpha, beta, data, j);                                                                                                   
      }                                                                                                                                           
      return sse;                                                                                                                                 
  }                                                                                                                                               

  var obsErr = function(alpha, beta, data, i) {                                                                                                   
      return (alpha + data[i]["x"] * beta) - data[i]["y"];                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                                               

  // Partial derivative of cost w.r.t. alpha                                                                                                      
  var pJpAlpha = function(alpha, beta, data) {                                                                                                    
      var sum = 0;                                                                                                                                
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {                                                                                                               
          sum += obsErr(alpha, beta, data, i);                                                                                                    
      }                                                                                                                                           
      //return sum;                                                                                                                               
      return Math.sqrt(2 * costFuncLR(alpha, beta, data));                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                                               

  // Partial derivative of cost w.r.t. beta                                                                                                       
  var pJpBeta = function(alpha, beta, data) {   
     var sum = 0                                                                                                                                 
      for (var j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {                                                                                                              
          sum += obsErr(alpha, beta, data, j) * data[j]["x"];                                                                                     
      }                                                                                                                                           
      return sum;                                                                                                                                 
  }                                                                                                                                               

  // Performs one iteration of Gradient Descent.                                                                                                  
  var gradientDescentIter = function(data, alphaOld, betaOld, learningRate) {                                                                     
      var pjpa = pJpAlpha(alphaOld, betaOld, data)                                                                                                
      var pjpb = pJpBeta(alphaOld, betaOld, data)                                                                                                 
      var temp0 = alphaOld - (learningRate * pjpa);                                                                                               
      var temp1 = betaOld - (learningRate * pjpb);                                                                                                
      var alphaNew = temp0;                                                                                                                       
      var betaNew = temp1;                                                                                                                        
      var out = [];                                                                                                                               
      out.push(alphaNew);                                                                                                                         
      out.push(betaNew);                                                                                                                          
      console.log(costFuncLR(alphaNew, betaNew, data));                                                                                           
      return out;                                                                                                                                 
  }
```

I appreciate all your help in advance.

Somewhat unrelated, I'd like to display level sets of the cost function via a contour plot in the parameter space, or surface embedded in Euclidean 3-space (the z-axis being cost), and watch the parameters change in that space as well.  I found a post by mike bostock on how to use a contour plot, but

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I've done more or less exactly that [here](http://4c.ucc.ie/~larsko/cs6405/demo/gradient-descent.html) (code [here](https://github.com/larskotthoff/ml-demo)).

Comment: @Lars, I've noticed that your code has the same behavior as mine, which is reassuring as far as the correctness of the implementation is concerned.  It initializes the intercept parameter at zero, and if you input data that has a trend suggesting a nonzero intercept (say, b_0 around 30), then gradient descent doesn't properly converge to this value. Indeed, the intercept parameter stays very close to the initial position.  This holds in your code (where it is initialized at zero) and in my code (when it is initialized from a uniform distribution over the y-range of the data).

Comment: I would suspect numerical precision issues. Gradient descent is also quite susceptible to the parameter values.

Comment: Anyone coming here looking for an implementation of gradient descent in JavaScript, checkout [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/linear-regression-gradient-descent-javascript/).